# Как правильно использовать методы с интернетом в фрагментах ViewPager?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть 2 запроса один длиться 5 сек, другой 10 сек.

ViewPager создает 2 фрагмента сразу, а значит и 2 запроса происходят сразу. В итоге чтобы увидеть 1 фрагмент надо ждать 10-20 сек. Это не правильно. Да и трафик экономить надо...И зачем мне делать тысяче запросов если я хочу только одно окно увидеть

Создавать отдельные фрагмент без ViewPager не получится, так как нужна вся анимация viewPagerа.

минимальный фрагмент который создает ViewPager равен 1 по бокам.

В итоге я в безвыходном положении.

> Мне нужно используя ViewPager делать запросы только когда активен
>   фрагмент не затрагивая боковые фрагменты.

Незнаю правильно это или нет, но сделано в приложении ВК

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай в фрагментах проверку на видимость, когда пользователь зайдет в фрагмент будет вызов

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

c isVisibleToUser == true, тогда и можно сделать запрос.

Но ViewPager не просто так 2 фрагмента создает, это нужно чтобы пользователь как раз не ждал постоянно загрузки при переключении.